# What names of people (real or mythical) could a person compare oneself to in order to give the air of super-normal strength?

Tags: перевод

I was watching a show called *In the Army now*, and at 20:03, the journalist refers to himself as иван поддубный, which was translated as *superman*: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js955f5zdXU. So my question is, what are some other well-known (assuming that иван поддубный is well-known) references that alludes to one's super-normal strength. For example, in English, I could make a comparison to either *Schwarzeneggar* or *Hercules*, both of whom are very well known

Comment: This is a broad question, especially if you need all of the names. Both Schwarzenegger and Hercules are well-known in Russia. Maybe restrict it to the names from Russian culture only?

Comment: I am not looking for "all the names", just those that are most commonly used. At least in America, I can count them on my fingers. And I didn't want to restrict the list to "names of Russian culture only" as I have only a vague idea of what is well-known to Russians. Sure, it would be pretty safe to assume that Schwarzeneggar and Hercules are known by most people, but what about He-man...perhaps the He-man cartoon is super popular in Russia...perhaps not...but I'm not adverse to this cultural limitation if the list ended up being prohibitively large

Comment: If you look for the most frequent (and more or less generic) association - I'd suggest checking the usage of the name _d'Artagnan_. But if you are thinking of all the variations of some particular context for comparison with a real or fictional persona the list indeed gonna be huge.

Comment: @DK. I think, d'Artagnan is more about moral authority (with the sarcasm) rather than strength. At least in recent years.

Comment: @Dmitry yes, you are right, I've missed question's focus on the physical strength there.

Comment: @JMP - you are essentially asking for the whole list. I can tell you that He-Man won't likely make the list, but how can I answer your question without making this list?

Comment: Hercules, Геракл in Russian, is indeed one such character although it seems its use as a metaphor for strength and physical might has dwindled

Comment: Илья Муромец to add.